# Do trees work with fat data sets?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, forecasting

I have a data set of $200$ observations of $10,000$ features. I want to use this data to make numeric predictions of a target variable $y$. Will trees, in particular XGBoost, be useful here? I feel like the extremely fat nature of this data might cause problems but I'm not very familiar with trees and not sure what those problems could be.

Comment: With reference to your question title, I note that GBM is a model derived from many trees; the answer to this question could well be very different for a single tree, such as C&RT or C4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable to expect single trees, such as C&RT or C4.5 to have some difficulty with respect of a data set with many features. Single trees are by and large, greedy algorithms, so they will go to the most favourable variable without returning to the others. In the case of your data set with only 200 observations, using it 'as is' would only allow for a maximum depth of six layers, hence a maximum of 254 splits - well short of the 10k variables.

Ensembles of trees build shallow trees with many different initial splits - as a result, far more variables will be incorporated into the model.

200 observations is a pretty small dataset - it is probable that the default settings are better suited to larger data sets. In particular, consider the interaction depth (effectively the tree depth. Default setting of 6 in the gbm R package, which is probably too deep a tree for 200 obs), minimum observations in the terminal node (set to default 10 in the R package gbm- you might need to go lower as low as 3) and the subsampling fraction (bag.fraction in R - default of 0.5, effectively meaning your original 200 observations has is now 100 for each boosting iteration. You might need to increase)

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost is able to evaluate the importance of the feature to labels. You can train your trees with all features, then choose several the most important ones and train again until you reach your goal (results on cross-validation, etc.)